# Vifm startup: How to make vifm remember the last cursor/selector positions on startup?

Tags: vifm

Vifm remembers the the last cursor/selector positions, so for example, if you move into a folder that contains files and move the cursor to the last file of that directory, then leave the directory and enter it again, the cursor/selector will be at the last highlighted (in this example the last) file.

**How can I achieve this behavior on vifm startup?**
(So that the cursor/selector highlights the chain of all lastly highlighted items before exiting vifm?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation on command-line options ([here](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-options)):

> vifm starts in the current directory unless it is given a different directory
>   on the command line **or `'vifminfo'` includes `"savedirs"` (in which case
>   last visited directories are used as defaults)**.

From documentation on `'vifminfo'` option ([here](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27vifminfo%27)):

> `savedirs` - save last visited directory (requires `dhistory`)

Sample `vifmrc` actually includes this:

```
set vifminfo=dhistory,savedirs,chistory,state,tui,shistory,
    \phistory,fhistory,dirstack,registers,bookmarks,bmarks
```

If you're not using it or changed it, just make sure that `dhistory` and `savedirs` are both included.

Comment: Btw does Ranger have a similar option?

Comment: Recently my vifm doesn't save my marks, I have this code `set vifminfo=savedirs...` in my vifmrc too, but it doesn't save my marks when I close vifm

Comment: I found the solution, I had to use :w to save current settings in vifminfo file